# chef-client console logging vs resource execution log

Tags: logging, chef-infra

I see that the Chef::Log.info() output appears on top of the actual resource execution output whenever I use 'chef-client -l info -L '.

I would like to have Chef::Log.info() output along with the actual resource execution. How to do this ?

Comment: Then use the `log` resource instead of calling the class at compile time ? (any example code and output to get what you're after ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is Chef's two-pass execution model. I've got a detailed write up over at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ but basically any code in a recipe outside of a `ruby_block` resource or a few other special cases (lazy helpers, guard blocks, etc) gets run at compile time while the resource output you're talking about happens at converge time.